# Finding an alternate proof that the given equation has no integer solutions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let's suppose two integers a and b.
Prove that the equation 
$$a^3 + (a+1)^3 + (a+2)^3 + (a+3)^3 + (a+4)^3 + (a+5)^3 + (a+6)^3 = b^4 + (b+1)^4$$
has no integer solutions.
I have proved it this way. The modulo $7$ of the cubes of seven consecutive numbers are congruent to $0, 1, 1,-1,1,-1,-1$. This means their sum i.e. the right hand side of the equation is congruent to 0 modulo $7$ i.e. divisible by $7$. The modulo $7$ of the fourth power of seven consecutive numbers are congruent to $0, 1, 2, -3, -3, 2, 1$. Thus modulo $7$ of any two consecutive number is not equal to zero. So, left hand side of the equation is never divisible by $7$.
This proof is lengthy. Is there any shorter proof? Can this be proved without modular arithmetic? If so how?

Comment: Looks pretty short to me. Now the Classification of Finite Simple Groups - that's a long proof!

Comment: No, it is not lengthy. It is very short: $A\equiv 0\bmod 7$ and $B\not\equiv 0\bmod 7$. Hence $A\neq B$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Can this be proved without modular arithmetic?